# Cannot boot to Ubuntu anymore (Windows 11 - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS dual boot)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04, boot-repair

I have a Windows 11 - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS -dual boot on my device (Lenovo Ideapad 5) and I am currently not able to boot to Ubuntu. The issues started after I booted to Windows after a longer break (and installed the accumulated updates).

I can no longer get GRUB to show up when booting and when I try to change the booting order in BIOS, Ubuntu is missing from the list.

I have tried to reinstall and update grub in a live session but with grub-install command I get the error message: 'cannot find EFI directory.', and with update-grub command I get the error message: 'failed to get canonical path of /cow.'.

I have also tried using the boot-repair -tool to fix the problem, but got the following error message: 'Error: NVram is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr).' so I couldn't run the fixes.

I also thought about reinstalling Ubuntu (without losing my data) but for some reason the option for that is missing from the installation options.

If someone could give me some advice on what I should try next I would be grateful!

Comment: Windows feature update tend to change the boot order back to Windows, for convenience, because one or more reboots are needed. In those case all the users have to do is to change the boot order back to Ubuntu.

Comment: Also Windows updates may update UEFI reverting settings to defaults. And then UEFI setting for locking UEFI settings, your NVRAM may be turned on. Check all UEFI settings.

Comment: You can install Grub2Win in Windows. Set it as default. Boot into Ubuntu. Repair your Grub from there. Set it as default in UEFI. After major Windows upgrades repeat this proces or just use Grub2Win as default.

Comment: You can use a usb device with super_grub2_disk_hybrid or using this program in an ikki boot.iso 'burned' on such a device. This program searches all bootable operating systems on your computer an can boot those. Once booted into Ubuntu repair your Grub.